# Como não ignorar diretórios com o mesmo nome?

Tags: git, diretório

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
nbproject
public_html
   build
      index.min.html
      style.min.css
   index.html
   style.html
build
dist
```

Meu `.gitignore` para ignorar os arquivos de configuração do Netbeans está assim:

```
nbproject/
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml
```

O problema é que ele está ignorando todos os diretórios com nome **build**, inclusive o que está dentro da pasta "public_html" que não deveria ser ignorado.

Como faço para deixar de ignorar esse diretório?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use o *path* absoluto:

```
/build/
```

Também é possível usar `!` ou `!*` para limpar os padrões anteriores mas não recomendo esta solução.

[Documentação](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).